# Switch in Jenkins pipeline returns null, same switch in normal Groovy returns expected output

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have this `switch` in my code (context: Jenkins pipeline library):

```
def installOptions(filePath) {
    switch (filePath) {
        case ~/.*\.pom/:
            "-Dpackaging=pom -DpomFile=$filePath"
            break
        case ~/.*\.jar/:
            '-Dpackaging=jar'
            break
        case ~/.*-exe-archive.zip/:
            filePath = filePath.replace '-exe-archive.zip', '.pom'
            "-Dpackaging=zip -DpomFile=$filePath"
            break
        default:
            ''
            break
    }
}
```

Value of `filePath`: `'temp_downloads/merge/QA-9344/itextcore/java/main.pom'`

Expected value:

```
-Dpackaging=pom -DpomFile=temp_downloads/merge/QA-9344/itextcore/java/main.pom
```

Actual value:

```
null
```

---

When I use exactly the same `switch` in "normal" Groovy, I do get the expected output:

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper

class InstallJavaBranchArtifacts extends Script {

    static void main(String[] args) {
        InvokerHelper.runScript(InstallJavaBranchArtifacts, args)
    }

    def run() {
        println installOptions('temp_downloads/merge/QA-9344/itextcore/java/main.pom')
        println installOptions('temp_downloads/merge/QA-9344/itextcore/java/barcodes.pom')
        println installOptions('temp_downloads/merge/QA-9344/itextcore/java/itext7-barcodes-7.1.12-SNAPSHOT.jar')
    }

    def installOptions(filePath) {
        switch (filePath) {
            case ~/.*\.pom/:
                "-Dpackaging=pom -DpomFile=$filePath"
                break
            case ~/.*\.jar/:
                '-Dpackaging=jar'
                break
            case ~/.*-exe-archive.zip/:
                filePath = filePath.replace '-exe-archive.zip', '.pom'
                "-Dpackaging=zip -DpomFile=$filePath"
                break
            default:
                ''
                break
        }
    }
}
```

then this is my output:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/java ...
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass (file:/usr/share/java/groovy-2.4.17.jar) to method java.lang.Object.finalize()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
-Dpackaging=pom -DpomFile=temp_downloads/merge/QA-9344/itextcore/java/main.pom
-Dpackaging=pom -DpomFile=temp_downloads/merge/QA-9344/itextcore/java/barcodes.pom
-Dpackaging=jar

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Which is (apart from the illegal reflective access mumbo jumbo) the expected output.

So what do I need to do, to make a `switch` behave in the same way in a Jenkins pipeline library as in "normal" Groovy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jenkins pipeline runs your Groovy code using Groovy CPS interpreter, which deconstructs your code into parts and evaluates them in the continuous-passing style. In the case of your example, your `switch` statement misses the explicit `return`, and that is why evaluating a body of your function returns `null`.

There are two options to fix it.

1. You can add `@NonCPS` annotation to `installOptions` function implementation, and this way you will run the body of this function using regular Groovy Shell interpreter. This may work for you, because in the body of this function you are not calling any Jenkins Pipeline workflow steps, but only plain Groovy code.

   ```
      @NonCPS
      def installOptions(filePath) {
           switch (filePath) {
               case ~/.*\.pom/:
                   "-Dpackaging=pom -DpomFile=$filePath"
                   break
               case ~/.*\.jar/:
                   '-Dpackaging=jar'
                   break
               case ~/.*-exe-archive.zip/:
                   filePath = filePath.replace '-exe-archive.zip', '.pom'
                   "-Dpackaging=zip -DpomFile=$filePath"
                   break
               default:
                   ''
                   break
           }
       }
   ```
2. If you want to keep the execution of this code in the Groovy CPS mode, remove `break` from each case and add explicit `return` before every string you return from the switch case.

   ```
      def installOptions(filePath) {
           switch (filePath) {
               case ~/.*\.pom/:
                   return "-Dpackaging=pom -DpomFile=$filePath"                        
               case ~/.*\.jar/:
                   return '-Dpackaging=jar'
               case ~/.*-exe-archive.zip/:
                   filePath = filePath.replace '-exe-archive.zip', '.pom'
                   return "-Dpackaging=zip -DpomFile=$filePath"
               default:
                   return ''
           }
       }
   ```

If you want to read more about Groovy CPS, go and check the docs here - https://github.com/cloudbees/groovy-cps.

Comment: Thank you! That's a solution _and_ an explanation!

Comment: I think I'll go for the second solution, that looks like cleaner code.

Comment: Is the library method implicitly a `void` type return since it is specified as `def`? If type declaration was changed to `String installOptions`, would that help block this kind of undesired behavior?

Comment: Another proposal was to change the code to `if { } else { if { } else { if { } else { } } }` under the assumption that the regexes were wrong, but I was pretty damn sure of my regexes and I knew the issue had to be something else. And I abhor if/else monstrosities.

Comment: This gave me some ideas to refactor other code where we have the `@NonCPS` annotation to make it work, without actually knowing _why_ that annotation is needed. Thanks!

Comment: @MattSchuchard `def` != `void`. The continuous-passing style is a root cause in this particular case. It deconstructs into small parts that get evaluated, and in this case, no return statement in switch makes it not aware of the context. That is why OP has to either make the context explicit with `return`, or evaluate the code outside the CPS. Replacing `def` with `String` does not change anything.

Comment: FYI, in the alternative solution, the regexes were replaced with the `endsWith()` method.